# Cannot serve angular app from its container through nginx container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem showing basic angular page through nginx.
We have an angular and a nginx container.

This is nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        server_name angular_test.dev;

        proxy_cache_key $request_method$request_uri;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_methods GET;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1y;

        location /angular {
            proxy_pass https://angular:4200;
            rewrite ^/angular(.*)$ $1 break;
        }
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/angular_test.dev.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/angular_test.dev.key;      
    }
}
```

So, I built angular app with docker file like this

```
FROM node:10.16.0-alpine as node
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#RUN npm install -g @angular/cli 
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And this is docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  angular:
    container_name: angular
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./wanderkite
    expose:
      - 4200
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    #restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - ./nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache
      - ./certs/client:/etc/letsencrypt
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

I also cant access angular just by typing localhost:4200 in browser. So basically what I want is to server angular app through nginx both on different containers. Am I missing something here? I also checked log from angular container and it is saying that angular live development server is listening on localhost:4200. When I access page on my host machine (angular_test.dev), I get 404.

Comment: why are you trying to do this? this isn't how angular is intended to be served / hosted in a production environment, the npm start command is just for development purposes only.  The angular build process outputs a set of static files that can be served as a static site by any web server with some minor tweaks... read more here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: I saw a few use cases where nginx was on same container as angular app. So is that the correct configuration? each angular app with its own server (apache/nginx), and then one nginx container that is actually a reverse proxy?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with nginx or docker tbh.  But, my expectation would be that docker runs the build command and nginx is just configured to serve the outputted index.html on all requests to port 80/443, rather than running the angular dev server inside of a docker container with nginx pointed at the dev server.

Comment: Would you please post this as an answer, so I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: glad i could help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this isn't how angular is intended to be served / hosted in a production environment, the npm start command is just for development purposes only. The angular build process outputs a set of static files that can be served as a static site by any web server with some minor tweaks... read more here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

I'm not overly familiar with nginx or docker tbh and have never run a configuration like this. But, my general expectation from past deployments / configurations would be that docker runs the build command like

```
RUN ng build --prod
```

and nginx is just configured to serve the outputted index.html on all (non 404) requests to port 80/443, rather than running the angular dev server inside of a docker container with nginx pointed at the dev server.

the specific nginx configuration from the deployment guide is here:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a kubernetes guy so I am not sure about the syntax of your docker compose file but it looks like you have not exposed the 80 & 443 ports of the nginx container.

Comment: Actualy, they are exposed with ports command. Difference between ports and expose is that ports will be also exposed to host. Expose command will only expose ports to other docker containers, but NOT to the host.

Comment: Okay try doing exec in the nginx pod and then do ```curl https://angular:4200``` and see if the angular app is accessible from nginx container. install curl if it's not already installed.